# How to create custom views for CoreData entity parent/children setup?

Tags: listview, swiftui, core-data

I setup a `CoreData` model with one parent `Entity` (abstract) that has two child entities:
[image]

The purpose for my setup is to show all kinds of child entities in a single SwiftUI `List` even if they are of different type (in other words, getting different entities in a single `FetchRequest`). Now, each child entity has different attributes which I want to show in the `List` (and later also in a `NavigationView` detail part which I plan to implement). For example, child entity #1 (TaskBlock) has an attribute `title` which I want to list in my `List` and child entity #2 (TextBlock) has a `text` attribute accordingly. So, I cannot access some shared (identical) attribute (like `id` in my example) that is defined in the parent entity.

I assume I could make some `if` statements in the `List` to deal with this, but this is not flexible as I intend to add a lot more child entities.

So how can I add some kind of `rowView` for my `List` specific for each child class?

I tried to create an extension to my child classes (and also the parent class), for example:

```
extension Block {
    struct BlockRowView: View {
        let block: Block

        var body: some View {
            Text(block.id!.uuidString)
        }
    }
}
```

And in my `ContenView.swift`, I create my List in the following way:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Block.id, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "parent == nil"),
        animation: .default) private var blocks: FetchedResults<Block>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(Array(blocks), children: \.childrenArray) { block in
                NavigationLink {
                    VStack {
                        Text(block.id!.uuidString)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text(block.id!.uuidString) // <== This works but doesn't show what I want
                }
                
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            // Adding some elements
            let newItem = TaskBlock(context: viewContext)
            newItem.title = "New Task 1"
            newItem.id = UUID()
            newItem.status = 0
            
            let newItem2 = TaskBlock(context: viewContext)
            newItem2.title = "New Task 2"
            newItem2.id = UUID()
            newItem2.status = 1
            
            let newItem3 = TextBlock(context: viewContext)
            newItem3.text = "New Text 1"
            newItem3.id = UUID()
            
            newItem.addToChildren(newItem2)
            newItem.addToChildren(newItem3)
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code line which works is marked, but it will show the shared `id` attribute instead of what I want, a child specific attribute. How can I fix this?

Comment: I avoid working with inheritance in my model but to me it looks like you need a common attribute in Block other than id if you want to display that in the list.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for your reply. Do you have a suggestion of using CoreData and achieving what I want without inheritance?

Comment: As a general advice, don’t design your model to fit the UI but rather create a design that suits the data your app is using and then create/design the UI.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Honestly, I thought I did that. What I want to achieve is basically a parent/children relationship, while the children can be of different type. So I thought, a parent should have some sort of array or set with all the children inside, no matter what class the children (or at least a couple of specific classes, hence the subclass approach). I can think of a different way to achieve this behavior, for example have a children_id array. But that takes a lot more processing (fetching etc) when constructing the UI. Can you recommend a strategy?